# How to benchmark android application?

Tags: java, android, benchmarking

At work I am using Ubuntu and at home I am using windows 7. I would like to know how can I benchmark my android application on Ubuntu and windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DDMS and Systrace to break down what your app is doing and for how long.

As for "benchmarking," what do you mean by that? Do you want to see how long it takes to do something in your app?
It's usually more useful to just make sure you're doing things in the fastest way possible, rather than within a certain time window.

Comment: I so did not ask for what my app is doing. I want to see benchmark.

Comment: You can't just "benchmark" an app, unless there's some specific processing it does that you want timed. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: Yes, I would like to so long my app takes something that it is doing.

Comment: I would like to find a time my app takes to run a for loop against a normal java project

Comment: No, you don't want to make sure you're doing everything in the fastest way possible. That is called premature optimization and will make your code unreadable and unmaintainable in addition to being a giant waste of time. You do want to figure out where your bottlenecks are and optimize those as much as needed. Otherwise we'd all be coding in assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a code to specifically benchmark specific part of the code that I want. you can find it here:
http://farzad.devbro.com/android_benchmark/Devbro_Benchmark.java

Here is an example of the code to use:

```
Devbro_Benchmark.markStart("Label2"); //mark a begining
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    //you can create multiple markers at once. If you use the same marker name
    //it will simply add up the times for you
    Devbro_Benchmark.markStart("Label1");
    //some random code
    Devbro_Benchmark.markEnd("Label");
}
Devbro_Benchmark.markEnd("Label2"); // mark an ending

//once you are done with your markers you can display an extensive report which will be
//shown using the Log.d
Devbro_Benchmark.print_report();

//once you are done you can reset before redoing it.
Devbro_Benchmark.reset();
```

Comment: If I want to benchmark tiktok by writting  microbenchmark testcases, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are now two Jetpack [benchmarking libraries](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/benchmarking-overview). from the Android team.

[Macrobenchmarking](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/macrobenchmark-overview): Allows you to benchmark entire workflows

[Microbenchmarking](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/microbenchmark-overview): Enables benchmarking specific code in isolation.